# Select nodes with specific attribute children nodes using xpath

Tags: xml, vb.net, xpath

I am having small issue reading children nodes from parent node containing specific attribute.

Here is my xml:

```
<Players>
  <Group Sort="Attack">
    <Player Name="John"/>
    <Player Name="John"/>
  </Group>
  <Group Sort="Defense">
    <Player Name="Thomas"/>
    <Player Name="Frank"/>
  </Group>
</Players>
```

Here is my code:

```
Dim FullList As New XmlDocument
FullList.Load("FullList.xml")
Dim ReadPlayer as string = Nothing
Dim ReadList As XmlNodeList = FullList.SelectNodes("/Players/Group")

For Each ReadNode As XmlNode In ReadList
    If ReadNode IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim ReadNodeAttribute as XmlAttribute = ReadNode .Attributes("Sort")
        If ReadNodeAttribute IsNot Nothing Then
            If ReadNodeAttribute.Value = "Attack" then
                Dim answer As String = "YES"
                Dim NameList As XmlNodeList = FullList.SelectNodes("/Players/Group[@Sort = '" & ReadNodeAttribute.Value & "' ]/Player")
                For Each Name As XmlNode In NameList
                    If Name IsNot Nothing Then
                        Dim NameAttribute As XmlAttribute = Name.Attributes("Name")
                        If NameAttribute IsNot Nothing Then
                            MsgBox(NameAttribute.Value & answer)
                        End If
                    End If
                Next
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next
```

The problem is I don't get `NameAttribute.Value`

I think that there is problem with selecting nodes, but I am not sure where exactly.

Comment: The example code you posted works correctly.  I just tested it.  Your problem must be elsewhere.

Comment: hmmm.... I have chosen now one specific attribute value. So I noticed that the problem is only when I load all attributes and then work with, I`ll edit in a minute.

Comment: When I run your modified example, it still works fine.  It displays `"JohnYES"` twice, as expected.  So, it's still not clear what your issue is.  It is a rather bizarre, round-about way of selecting the data, though.  Perhaps if you just explained what you were trying to select and why, I could explain what I think would be the best way to do that.

Comment: Hmmm... If it works for you then i probably have fixed that issue while modyfying online. Need to test one more time when will be at home. The thing is that i was getting nothing in debugger when selecting nodes fulllist.selectnodes with that concrete attribute. Will test it one mkre time and let you know.

Comment: Ok, I found the problem it was here `'" & ReadNodeAttribute.Value & "'`, by mistake I made spaces between " and ' signs, so that created new word with spaces. This is why it was unable to locate node with specific attribute. Thanks Steven.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all you need to do is get the list of player names where the `Sort` property of their group equals `"Attack"`, you could just do something like this:

```
Dim doc As New XmlDocument()
doc.Load("test.xml")
For Each ReadNode As XmlNode In doc.SelectNodes("/Players/Group[@Sort='Attack']/Player/@Name")
    MessageBox.Show(ReadNode.InnerText)
Next
```

Comment: Like I mentioned I have much bigger base of attributes, and for every attribute, I want to add different strings to use later in work. But your answer is good too. Thanks Steven.

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested to use `XLINQ` for this, you could use(`Imports System.Xml.XPath`):

```
    Dim xDoc = <Players>
               <Group Sort="Attack">
                   <Player Name="John"/>
                   <Player Name="John"/>
               </Group>
               <Group Sort="Defense">
                   <Player Name="Thomas"/>
                   <Player Name="Frank"/>
               </Group>
           </Players>
Dim query = xDoc.XPathSelectElements("//Group[@Sort='Attack']/Player")

For Each ele In query
    MsgBox(ele.@Name)
Next ele
```

Comment: LINQ is good, but I decided to keep doing xpath to prevent myself from confusing. Thanks.